# How to use rails Paperclip to upload images without using a form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, paperclip

I know that with the paperclip gem for rails I can upload images to the server like this.

```
<%= form_for @object, :method => :POST, html: { multipart: true }  do |f| %> 
  <%= f.file_field :image %> 
<% end %>
```

But since I am using ReactJs, I want to do a pure html file upload. I have been trying to do it this way:

```
<form className="new_object" id="new_object" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/objects" method="post">             
  <input className="upload" type="file" name="object[image]" id="object_image" /> 
</form>
```

Every time I upload the image I get `Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError` in `ObjectsController#create` error.

At this point I don't know what the problem is, so any help would be great !

Comment: You need to send it as base64 to your backend. I am on my phone, once I get to a computer I will post code but I thought to help.

Comment: okay thank you. some code would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem, thanks in part to mohamed. I had to encode the file that was uploaded to base64 using javascript, then I had to submit that value though a hidden input field.

Then everything started working !